# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded with fastcgi_read_timeout 2400 max_execution_time = 2400 and max_input_time = 2400

Tags: php, mongodb, neo4jphp

I have:

```
 FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

My php settings are:

```
 fastcgi_read_timeout 2400;
 fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "max_execution_time = 2400";
 fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "max_input_time = 2400";
 fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "memory_limit = 1024M";
```

I'm doing massive doctrine-mongodb and neo4j flush operations

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the PHP_VALUE every time, only setting the memory_limit.
Try

```
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "max_execution_time = 2400
                           max_input_time = 2400
                           memory_limit = 1024M";
```